# UIScrollView Segues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I've implemented a UIScrollView with the UIPageControl with a UIViewController that has a UIButton with a segue , the problem when I click the UIButton the segue is made but inside the ScrollView not filling the full screen?

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to state that you have one UIViewController that has a UIButton in it and another UIViewController that has a UIScrollView; When you press the button on the first view the segue activates and the second view with the scrollView appears but the scrollView isn't taking up the full screen? If this is the case connect an IBOutlet variable to the UIScrollView and set its frame to the full size of the screen. 
`-(void)viewDidLoad{
self.mainScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
}`